# Safari iCloud Tabs: iOS does not show macOS Safari tabs

Tags: macos, icloud, safari, ios, tabs

I had a problem where both my Mac OSX and iPhone iOS10 stopped sharing iCloud tabs. So I logged out from both iCloud accounts and signed in again.

Now my Mac shows iPhone tabs but not vice versa. **How can I display the Mac's Safari tabs on my iPhone?**

Comment: What version of macOS / iOS are you using and how did you check for your Mac's Safari tabs on you iPhone?

Comment: @oa- MAC OSX and IOS10 , by opening tabs and scrolling to the end

Comment: Can you add this information to your question and include the _version_ of macOS/OS X?

Comment: @oa- I added them as tags to the question, but sure